# junit test case for FTP

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, ftp, code-coverage

Can some one tell me how to write a junit test case for the following  piece of code. 
The one i have written doesn't get enter into the try body. why..??

code:-

```
public void dataImport ( String scheme , String dataSource , String savePath ) throws ImportException {
    LOG.debug("Entered");
    final InputStream inputStream = null ;

    try {
            String host = "localhost";
            String user = "user";
            String pass = "pass";
            String filePath ="/A/a1.txt";     ( this are actually extracted from dataSource )
            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
          ftpClient.connect(host, 21);
          ftpClient.login(user, pass);
          inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(filePath);

          //saving it to the file System

          }

    catch (final IOException ex) { 
          throw new ImportException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
          }

    finally {
          try {
            if (inputStream != null) {
              inputStream.close();
            }
          } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new ImportException(e.getMessage(), e);
          }
        }
        }
```

Junit test case:-

```
 @Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
  public void testImportData () throws ImportException , IOException {
  FTPImporter fi = new FTPImporter();
  try{ 
  fi.dataImport("ftp" , "ftp://user:pass@localhost/A/a1.txt" , "desti" );
  fail("ere");
  }
  catch(ImportException e ){
  assertNotNull(e.getMessage());
 }
 }
```

Comment: You don't seem to be calling DataImport from your test case.

Comment: word of advice, method names should always start with a lower case character.

Comment: What do you see when you run it? ( log output etc )

Comment: I have used sonar with jococo plugin , in the code coverage report of the same I can see it not entering in the try body. Is my test case not a valid one ..??

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `FTPImporter` constructor succeeds?
Check your logs, debug `testImportData` method in IDE or wrap `new FTPImporter()` in try-catch block and log exception, something like this:

```
FTPImporter fi = null;
try {
    fi = new FTPImporter();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    fail("Error!");
}
```

Chance is your constructor throws `NullPointerException` which is expected by this test.

Comment: yes it did succeed , even anything outside the try block is getting covered.

Comment: trying your block of test case gives the error:-
*void type not allowed here*

Comment: No this time the constructor didn't get invoked.

Comment: I'm sure this time you'll have stacktrace logged somewhere. Check contents of your output text console for exception's stacktrace. I don't use sonar so I don't know where you can find output console recordings. I recomend running this particular test manually from your IDE and observing Console output.